# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}F(\sin \pi x)\;dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $F : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$F(s) = \begin{cases}
1, & s \geq 1/2 \\
      0, &s < 1/2
\end{cases}$$

Evaluate  $\int_{0}^{1}F(\sin \pi x)\;dx$.

My Attempt :  $\sin\pi x = 1/2$ when $x=1/6$ and $\sin\pi x =0$ when $x =0$.

Here I got the value $ F(s)=F(\sin\pi/6) =F(1/2) =1$.

Similarly $F(\sin(\pi\cdot 0))= 0$.

Now I evaluate the $\int_{0}^{1/2}F(0)\;dx + \int_{1/2}^{1}F(1/2)\;dx$. I got the answer $1/2$.

Is my answer correct or not,  I would be more thankful if someone rectify my mistakes...

Comment: It helps to sketch the function. Then you see the Sin fn rises above 1/2 at $x=1/6$ but it also falls below 1/2 at $x=5/6$.  You are integrating to measure the area beneath a function which is height $1$ in-between these points and is zero outside them.

Answer (score 1):

This function is $0$ between $x=0$ to $x=1/6$ and is $0$ from $x=5/6$ to $x=1$, and it is $1$ in-between.

So it should enclose the area $1\times\frac{5-1}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: im not getting at x= 1/6 how it becomes zero  ...as F(sin(pi/6)= F(1/2)= 1 @ robert frost

Comment: @legohlegoh at $x=1/6$, s becomes $1/2$ and F becomes $1$. Sketch sin x. Then overlay F over that.

Comment: @legohlegoh it should look like a camel's hump crossing the x axis at $0$ and $1$, with a rectangle of height $1$ between $1/6$ and $5/6$ on the x-axis.